# VSTO Outlook add-in: is warning/alert pane in mail compose accessible to code

Tags: outlook, vsto

In my VSTO custom Outlook add-in I was looking for a programmatic way to display a warning/alert to the user just like Outlook does when an external recipient is added to an email in which case in the mail compose explorer/inspector the "The following recipient is external to your organization" message is displayed.

Is leveraging of the warning/alert pane exposed in the API?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a alertbox in API but you can create a new Windows Form and check reciepents on mailItem.ItemSend event.

Open a form in as a dialog makes you can retrieve response and you can Cancel the process or continue with the answer.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ItemSend += new ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(ItemSend);
}


void ItemSend(Object item, ref bool Cancel)
{
   Form form= new XForm();
   DialogResult res = form.ShowDialog();
   if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
   {
        Cancel = true;
   }
   else
   {
      ....       
   }     
}
```

Hope it will help.